# how to iterate and compare data in an object

Tags: javascript

I'm writing an ATM console program which validate user with pin.Now when ever users tries to use it,it asks for their pin and brings any name associated to that particular pin but i have not been unable to achieve that.It's the only thing left for me in this little project as i hav coded the rest and they are working okay.The below is the code for pin validation.

```
function Authentication(){
    let LoginAcess = [
        {"name" : "bradly cooper", "pass" : 1990},
        {"name" : 'james berry', "pass" : 1989},
        {"name" : "sarah lance", "pass" : 1980},
    ]
    for (let records in LoginAcess){
        eachRecord = LoginAcess[records];
        console.log(eachRecord)
        let pin = prompt("enter your 4 valid digit pin : ");
        if (pin === eachRecord.pass){
            console.log(eachRecord.name)
        }
    }
};
Authentication();
```

Comment: This is backwards to begin with - I doubt you want to ask the user for their PIN as many times, as you have records in `LoginAcess` …?

Comment: _“it asks for their pin and brings any name associated to that particular pin”_ - that’s not what I would call _“validat[ing] user with pin”_ to begin with. Why would you give me the name of someone that isn’t even me, just because I might have typed in _their_ PIN? Is that how ATMs work where you’re from …?

Comment: i actually created 3 users in so as to make sure all users can login according to their pin.users wont be asked to supply pins many times.just a single pin assinged to a single user.lets say once i supply 1980,the machine will display "welcome sarah lance" or when i supply 1989 the machine will display "welcome james berry".

Comment: that name serves as user details in the database.Here why i'm from pins are assigned to every users using atm here.Thats one of thei identification.

Comment: _“users wont be asked to supply pins many times”_ - well with what you have written, they will be - you are looping over all three records you got there, and you are asking them _inside_ of that loop.

Comment: _“lets say once i supply 1980,the machine will display "welcome sarah lance" or when i supply 1989 the machine will display "welcome james berry"”_ - that is what I would call a _search_ at most then, but not actually _validating_ user access with a PIN.

Answer (score 1):

the value in the variable `pin` is a string.

```
if (pin === eachRecord.pass){
    console.log(eachRecord.name)
}
```

you are comparing string and number.
You can convert string to number by using parseInt(pin) or Number(pin)

```
if (parseInt(pin) === eachRecord.pass){
    console.log(eachRecord.name)
}
```

Comment: i just did that but now the issue is its requesting for pin 3 times instead of once but once i supplies correct pin,it displayed the equivalent name to it which is what i wanted but i don't want it to request for pins 3 time.just once.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it without looping for better performance by using the below piece of code.

```
let  LoginAcess = [
        {"name" : "bradly cooper", "pass" : 1990},
        {"name" : 'james berry', "pass" : 1989},
        {"name" : "sarah lance", "pass" : 1980},
    ];

var pin ; // pin is input taken from user

var userName = (LoginAcess.find(({ pass }) => pass == pin)["name"]);
```

You will get the name as output. if you want to get the entire object as output remove "["name"]".

Comment: this worked perfectly and sorted what i wanted.now i can have multiple data in the object and get the name of the only associated pin.I appreciate this.Thanks once again

Answer (score 1):

for...in is to iterate on properties object :

```
for ( propertie in objet ) { ... }
```

instead use find() :

```
let userIn = LoginAcess.find( element => element.pass == pin );
```

Comment: The find() method returns the value of the first element in the provided array that satisfies the provided testing function. read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find if I help you can you upvote and/or accept my answer please

Answer (score 1):

you have to put let pin = prompt("enter your 4 valid digit pin : "); out of the bucle.
In python is very easy:

```
def Authentication():
    LoginAcess = [{"name" : "bradly cooper", "pass" : 1990},{"name" : 'james berry', "pass" : 1989},{"name" : "sarah lance", "pass" : 1980}]
    pin = input('enter your 4 valid digit pin: ')
    for record in LoginAcess:
        print('checking record' + str(record))
        if(pin == record['pass']):
            print("USER WITH PIN SELECTED FOUND")
            print(record['name'])
            return
        else:
            print("user: " + str(record['name']) + " does not match input pin")

Authentication()
```

you can analyze this python code and change yours

Comment: yes i did let already.ive actually written this code in python and it works well

Comment: so did you solve it? i think if you just change the prompt out of the loop and also use record variable instead of reading the variable eachRecord (Because you already have it in the loop) it should work in Js